# debug_traceBlockByNumber 'callTracer' call is hanging on block 11092712

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a tracer that traces each block using the 'callTracer' tracer but yesterday it go stuck on block 11092712. When i try to curl Geth with a request to trace this block, it hangs and eventually times out (timeout = 100s). Any ideas what the issue might be? I can successfully curl the block before and after this one.